# Solidity Token Address

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, bep20

```
contract Trail is IBEP20, Auth {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    address DEAD = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    address ZERO = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    address routerAddress = 0x; // MAINNET

    string constant _name = "";
    string constant _symbol = "";
    uint8 constant _decimals = 9;

    uint256 _totalSupply = 10000000000000000 * (10 ** _decimals);
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = _totalSupply; 
    uint256 public _maxWalletSize = (_totalSupply * 1) / 100; 

    mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) isFeeExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) isTxLimitExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) isTimelockExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) public isBot;

    uint256 liquidityFee = 1;
    uint256 devFee = 2; 
    uint256 marketingFee = 5;
    uint256 totalFee = 8;
    uint256 feeDenominator = 100;
    uint256 public _sellMultiplier = 1;
    
    address public marketingFeeReceiver = 0x;
    address public devFeeReceiver = msg.sender;

    IDEXRouter public router;
    address public pair;

    uint256 public launchedAt;
}
```

What is the "routerAddress" meaning? And also "marketingFeeReceiver" is the owner of the coin, right? I saw this code on bscscan newly verified, I'm trying to understand but I'm newbie at cryptocurrency. Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the "routerAddress" meaning?

`routerAddress` is a variable where inside it will be inserted the value about PancakeSwapRouter.
In this smart contract, he's implementing this router contract because he want make available the swap in a DEX (in this case Pancakeswap) between his token and others tokens or coin (BNB in this case).
In details, a router contract performs the safety checks needed for safely swapping, adding, and removing liquidity.

You can read more about this topic [here](https://uniswap.org/blog/uniswap-v2).

> And also "marketingFeeReceiver" is the owner of the coin, right?

This variable CAN hold the address owner of the coin but in most project its value refers to address multisig wallet concern the project and where all fees will transfer.

Comment: so i'll write ```0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E``` to ```routerAdress```, and i should create a random wallet for ```marketingFeeReceiver```, am I understand right?

Comment: multisig wallets looking like a wallet id with encoded